# sync data from file to database

Tags: java, oracle

Scenario

I have employee objects in a file(flat file), each row representing one employee record

I have employee objects in Database table employee

I want to sync the records in file to table employee
insert those which are not in table
update those which are there, but some fields are updated
delete those records which aer not in file, but exists in table

One simple solution(not sure, if this is correct) I can think of :
delete all the records from Dababase table, and insert all the reocrds in file to table

But I want to update those, which exists already, but one or more field is changed

Note: employee_id is unique/primary key to identify a record, and there are no duplicate records in file or table

Comment: In case you have access to create new table, you can add a table pumping in records from the flat file. Now you can reconcile or manipulate records in existing table running SQL script.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary table which has the same columns with the employee table.  Load the data from the file to the temporary table first, and then it’s pure sql operation.
For example, delete those not in the file

```
Delete from employee where employee_id not in (select employee_id from employee_tmp);
```

insert those in the file but not in the table

```
insert into employee select * from employee_tmp where empoyee_id not in (select employee_id from employee)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer,please elaborate how you compare the records